# Start of Simple Java program causes a white screen pause

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a simple text program and am loading the jframe with 2 JPanels(body and footer) a text area for the body and lable for the footer. I am not sure if my ordering is wrong or i forgot something but i get a lag when starting the program that causes it to blink white. This is kind of annoying and i would like to avoid this if possible. Any thoughts?

---

This is what it should look like but at the start it blinks white and hands for half a second.
I tried setting the frame background to blue too but that didnt change anything.

[image: hangs here][image: should look like this...]

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SIMPLE TEXT");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
    JPanel footer = new JPanel();       
    JLabel linecol = new JLabel("line: 0 col: 0");

    frame.setSize(640,480);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    panel.setSize(frame.getBounds().width, frame.getBounds().height);
    panel.setBackground(bgColor);
    panel.setForeground(fgColor);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    footer.setSize(640,20);
    footer.setBackground(bgColor);
    footer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    footer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,10));

    textarea.setSize(400, 400);
    textarea.setOpaque(false);
    textarea.setForeground(fgColor);
    textarea.setCaretColor(fgColor);


    linecol.setForeground(fgColor); 


    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    panel.add(textarea);
    footer.add(linecol, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Comment: call setvisible at end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this `frame.setVisible(true);` and move it to the list command you call after the screen has been built

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("SIMPLE TEXT");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
JPanel footer = new JPanel();       
JLabel linecol = new JLabel("line: 0 col: 0");

//frame.setSize(640,480);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//frame.setVisible(true);
//frame.setResizable(false);

//...

frame.add(panel);
panel.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
panel.add(textarea);
footer.add(linecol, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

frame.setResizable(false);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You will also find that using `setSize` to try and size your components is pointless (and highly discouraged) as the frame and panels are under the control of a layout manager...

Also beware, `setResizable` can change the size of the frame's borders, this needs to be called before you try and size and/or position the window.

**Updated**

As suggested by Andrew Thompson, you should be using [`JTextArea(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea(int,%20int)) to provide sizing hints to the layout manager.  You may also find the `JTextArea` more useful if you were to place it within a `JScrollPane`.  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: *"You will also find that using `setSize` to try and size your components is pointless.."* Carrying on from that thought, it would be best to change `JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();` to something like `JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(5,30);` to **suggest** a size to the layout manager.